# Contenteditable rich text editor doesn't generate an error message when empty

Tags: javascript, php, contenteditable

My textarea doesn't generate an error message when empty. This is the textarea:

`<textarea id="wmd-input" name="<?php echo $wmd_editor['name']; ?>"><?php echo $wmd_editor['content']; ?></textarea>`

It's passed like this in the post.php page:

```
<?php

if(richTextAllowed(time())) {
$wmd_editor = array("name"=>"addesc", "content"=>$data['addesc']);
include("{$path_escape}editor/wmd_editor.inc.php");
} else {
?>

<?php
}
?>
```

And the error is generated by:

```
function checkPostFields(form) {
var msg = '';
var value_missing = false;
if (form.elements['addesc'].value == ''
|| form.elements['adtitle'].value == ''
|| form.elements['email'].value == ''
<?php if ($image_verification) { ?>
|| form.elements['captcha'].value == ''
<?php } ?>
) {
msg += '<?php echo $lang['ERROR_POST_FILL_ALL']; ?>\n';
value_missing = true;
}
if (!form.elements['agree'].checked) {
msg += '<?php echo $lang['ERROR_POST_AGREE_TERMS']; ?>\n';
}
<?php
if(count($xsubcatfields)) {
foreach($xsubcatfields as $fldnum=>$fld) {
if ($fld['REQUIRED']) {
?>
if (!value_missing && !form.elements['x[<?php echo $fldnum; ?>]'].value) {
msg = '<?php echo $lang['ERROR_POST_FILL_ALL']; ?>\n' + msg;
value_missing = true;
}
<?php
}
}
}
?>
if (msg != '') {
alert(msg);
return false;
}
}
```

Everything works fine when I use just the textarea, but once the rich text editor's settings applied (contenteditable) the textarea allows to post messages even if there's no content in it.